# How to ask Chinese tourists keep their voice down?

Tags: translation, word, traditional-characters

**Background:**

In Silom, Thailand, I was eating in a small restaurant, 5x10 square meters. It is not a quiet place since it is located nearby the road. However, customers in here, for example white people and Thai locals, normally speak very low and leave after they finish. But 10 Chinese tourists came in and started ordering food, talking loud, like shouting. Their loud voices made me very nervous. No idea if they will talk to local people with the same sound level or not since they use hand method to order.

**Question:**

Direct translatation from English of `Lower your voice please` to Chinese is `请降低你的声音`. Is it ok?

Comment: customers generally resent requests by other customers, if management does not protest to noisy customers, nothing can be done, the same goes for bus travel, drivers usually would request noisy passengers to tone down their voices, but protests by other passengers are generally resented, 

一般来说所有顾客对别顾客那样的请求会感到愤怒，老板不插嘴的话就无可奈何，公共汽车旅行也是如此，司机平时会请求吵闹乘客降低音量，可是别乘客的反对很可能和所期望的结果完全相反

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the best sentence to let them know that they are making very loud noise?*

Before I give out example sentences for asking people to lower their voice, I have to warn you-- Telling strangers that their behavior is unacceptable in public might lead to verbal confrontation or worse.

- Some people might think talking loud is their personal right, telling them otherwise is an intrusion.  No words of yours can change their behavior.
- Some people might not notice they are being loud. They can be reasoned with, but you have to be extremely polite. You are pointing out something they do wrong after all. No one like to be criticized.

Now there are some example sentences you could use.

1. Start with "對不起" /duìbùqǐ/ (excuse me/ sorry).
2. Then beg them "能請你們" /Néng qǐng nǐmen/(would you please).
3. Tell them what you want, "降低聲量嗎?"/Jiàngdī shēngliàng ma/ (lower your voice?).
4. (optional) Make them think you are with them "外国人爱挑剔别人大声说话" /Wàiguó rén ài Tiāotì biérén dàshēng shuōhuà/ (Foreigners love to pick on people who use loud voice).
5. Thank them for cooperating "谢谢合作" /Xièxiè hézuò/. After being thanked, most reasonable people would not be able to get too angry with you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aware that criticizing people might lead to confrontation. That is the reason why I have to ask in here first before facing them next time.

Comment: @Sarit Maybe you could post a sign at the entrance to avoid confrontation. Chinese people just love being loud. The sign might help with future Chinese costumers as well.

Comment: @ Enrico Brasil Chinese government has been trying to educate Chinese citizens to act more considerate abroad. The problem is what foreigners consider 'loud', In many Chinese's eyes is just 'being lively' (saying Chinese people just love being loud is a little bit unfair)

Comment: When Chinese people travel abroad, THEY are the foreigners. If the locals think they're loud, then they are...

Comment: @EnricoBrasil I think so thank you. Since the place is small and decorate with many menus on the door and walls already. I would try my best to convince restaurant owner to put the label on it. Hope this help :)